# Does Hangfire create automatic database?

Tags: .net, .net-core, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire but using memory storage to understand first how it works. Sadly today I was accessing my azure platform and I was being charged on sql server for something I was not recognizing.

After a lot time I realized Hangfire had created a second database and applied an expansive cost plan for this and I can't understand why Hangfire created that database if I was using memory storage.

I have only 3 code lines about Hangfire in my application and I'm really worried about how it happened.

On my startup I have inserted:

```cs
services.AddHangfire(op => op.UseMemoryStorage());
services.AddHangfireServer();
```

and:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
 endpoints.MapControllers();
 endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();
});
```

Why would Hangfire create an sql database if I was not using sql at this moment?

Comment: Hangfire does not have any connection with Hangfire.MemoryStorage. They were createad by different people and Hangfire.MemoryStorage is only for testing.

Comment: See https://github.com/perrich/Hangfire.MemoryStorage